# How do I properly renew my PATs so that my deployment groups do not stop working due to expiration of the PAT?

Tags: azure-devops

When does a Deployment Group stop working due to expiration or regeneration of the Personal Access Token (PAT) that it was configured with?

If I regenerate the PAT, do I need to update the deployed agents, e.g. reconfigure them with the new PAT?

What happens if I just edit the PAT, update the Expiration date, but don't do anything else, e.g. do not regenerate the PAT or do any changes at the configured deployment agent? Will it stop it from expiring and the configured deployment agent still work?

We have Azure DevOps pipeline, along with a deployment group configured to install the solution to one server.

We have a service account, which we use have generated a PAT and used that token to configure the Deployment Group.

I have tried to regenerate the token, which gave me a new PAT. I have not tried to configure the server with the new PAT. However, deployments still seem to work just fine hours from regenerating the PAT.

What is the proper way to update the PAT so that it does not expire and my deployment agents do not stop working?

Comment: Apparently some help can be found here.

https://veegens.wordpress.com/2017/07/21/vsts-pat-used-for-build-agent-expires-now-what/

PAT is not persisted, so the deployment group will continue working just fine, as long as I don't go and change the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#authentication):

> To register an agent, you need to be a member of the administrator
> role in the agent pool. The identity of agent pool administrator is
> needed only at the time of registration and is not persisted on the
> agent, and is not used in any subsequent communication between the
> agent and Azure Pipelines or TFS. In addition, you must be a local
> administrator on the server in order to configure the agent.
>
> Your
> agent can authenticate to Azure Pipelines or TFS using one of the
> following methods: Personal Access Token (PAT): Generate and use a PAT
> to connect an agent with Azure Pipelines or TFS 2017 and newer. PAT is
> the only scheme that works with Azure Pipelines. **Also, as explained
> above, this PAT is used only at the time of registering the agent, and
> not for subsequent communication.**

So, if you remove or re-generate the PAT the agents will keep working without any issues.

Comment: for me this was incorrect, my PAT expired and the deploymenst started to fail

Comment: I can verify this. The user that made the PAT token were transferred to another project, and only recently did the deployments start to fail. The solution was to make the original user extend the expiry date, or to generate one's own PAT token and to use that instead. Looking for better ways to authenticate, rather than through PAT tokens.

Comment: @DaniëlTulp or Fhyarnir can you all please shed more light on the particular scenario since your observation contradicts MSFT's official statement ?

Comment: that PAT that expired had nothing to do with the deployment failing, or at least we think it didn't, we were never able to solve the failing agent, we just created a new VPS and installed a fresh agent there which worked and this one has not failed since

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. You can Edit token and change expiration date, this is the easiest way
2. You can Regenerate token, this will create new token, and you will have to:

   2.1. **Write down your agent user capabilites, name, service user account etc.! Because once you remove the configuration this information will be lost**

   2.2 Remove agent's configuration  (in agent's folder), run ".\config.cmd remove"

   2.3 Configure agent with new PAT (in agent's folder), run ".\config.cmd"